# Find Radius for addProximityAlert android

Tags: android, maps

I am having Starting lat and lng and Ending lat and lng.I am using addProximityAlert for the alert event. And i want to fire the alert at some time say xmin before the end lat and lng.
so i need to calculate the radius.

how can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

I am new but here is the way to do it.

When creating the alert add extra info (including the radius you set or an id that can be linked to a list of locations with their radii)

In my case my locs, are a collection of objects (loc) with ids, lat, lon, and dist

```
Intent intent = new Intent(com.repliq.RingZones2Personal.RingZoneService.class.getName());
```

here is where you add it...

```
intent.putExtra("id", loc.getID());

PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, loc.getID(), intent, 0);
                        locationManager.addProximityAlert(loc.getLat(), loc.getLon(), loc.getDist(), -1, proximityIntent);
```

In your proximity intent receiver you can get all the extra info back

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    int zoneid = extras.getInt("locid", -1);
```

Hope this helps.
yalcin